# How to disable constraints on a parameterized query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I cannot determine why the following code breaks with an exception of: System.Data.ConstraintException. I'm not sure why constraints are even being considered, since all I'm doing is reading a datatable.

How do I relax constraints on the parameter query below?

```
If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_spaRef)) And (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_cusRef)) Then
    Using adpt As New SoftwareSolutions_DataSetTableAdapters.view_SpaCreditDifferencesTableAdapter
        Dim dt = adpt.GetAdjustmentsListByIndex(_spaRef, _cusRef).Rows
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt
            lbxAdjustments.Items.Add(dr("adjNumber").ToString())
        Next
    End Using
End If
```

Comment: You probably have constraints within the database, and your operation hurts them.

Comment: What operation? I'm not doing anything to the table, I'm reading the results of a sql query into a local private variable.

Comment: I see. As I read this exception "Represents the exception that is thrown when attempting an action that violates a constraint." Do you get any details in the error message which describes what the constraint was?

Comment: Well, the message is "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints", however, I'm not sure why it's even trying to enable constraints. I'd like to disable them entirely, but I'm not sure how to do that with a parameter query. 

`dv = adpt.GetAdjustmentsListByIndex(_spaRef, _cusRef).DataSet.EnforceConstraints = False`

Doesn't work

Comment: I am not an expert in this, sorry if giving you wrong hints. The last one: do you have some database connection, or database login, which contains the trigger enable command?